# How do you making javascript blocking code?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

As an example, I want this code to output:
// Delayed 3000s, Delayed 2000s, Delayed 1000s

But it's outputting the below because the loop moves faster than the promise.
// Delayed 1000s, Delayed 2000s, Delayed 3000s

How can I write this code so it outputs in a sequential order?

```js
// Delay function
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// main function
async function main(x) {
  await sleep(x);
  console.log(`Delayed ${x}s`);
}

let arr = [3000,2000,1000];
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  main(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: `await` it inside the loop

Comment: Add `await` here: `await dummy(arr[i])`.

Comment: // Delay function
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// main function
async function main(x) {
   sleep(x);
  console.log(`Delayed ${x}s`);
}

async function xyz() {
let arr = [3000,2000,1000];
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  await main(arr[i]);
}
}

xyz()